# Need help to rewrite Apps Script so it doesn't need to loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script that loops through each URL in a long list of URLs. Unfortunately, because it goes through each one individually it exceeds the maximum execution time (6 minutes). Is there a faster way to get through my list of almost 28,000 URLs?

```
function getData() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('URL2');

 var firstURL = 1
 var lastURL = 27886


 var i
 for (i=firstURL; i<lastURL; i++) {
  var data = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(data, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText();

  //Logger.log(data)
  //Logger.log(response)

  if (response.toLowerCase().indexOf("cast</tt></a> <tt>area")>-1) {
    //Logger.log(1)
    sheet.getRange(i,2).setValue(1);
  }
  else{
    sheet.getRange(i,2).setValue(0);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution:

Please read the [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) to learn how to use batch operations.

This should be way faster:

```
function getData() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('URL2'); 
 const urls = sheet.getRange('A1:A2000').getValues().flat(); // Run this in batches
 const data = urls.map(url=>{
   let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText();
   return [response.includes("cast</tt></a> <tt>area") ? 1: 0];
 })
 const brow=sheet.getRange('B1:B').getValues().filter(String).length+1;
 sheet.getRange(brow,2,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

### Important info:

Note [that](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) consumer accounts and business accounts have a limit of 20k and 100k of URL fetch calls respectively on a **daily** basis. Since you can only run scripts for 6 minutes it means that you don't have a business account and therefore you can fetch only 20k urls per day. Assuming you already fetched some URLs today, you might have already consumed some of your daily quota, so be careful with this.

[image]

**Please Note!**

Run your code in batches: from `A1:A2000` then from `A2001:A4000` etc, so you make sure the script is not terminated in the middle of the process and then you don't get anything back in the sheet. I adjusted the code so you can continue pasting from the last entry in column B.

Also `UrlFetchApp.fetch` is a slow method, so it will still take some time. However, from `GAS` or `JavaScript` point of view, the code is very efficient.